# Woocommerce not showing tab content in my custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I copied tabs.php from woocomerce and placed inside my theme to override the file. Overriding works.

The tabs titles showing up but the content for the tabs not showing up regardless of the template placed in theme or the original template in the plugin. This is how the `tabs.php` looks like:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/**
 * Filter tabs and allow third parties to add their own.
 *
 * Each tab is an array containing title, callback and priority.
 * @see woocommerce_default_product_tabs()
 */
$tabs = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', array() );

if ( ! empty( $tabs ) ) : ?>

<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($tabs);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
        <div class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper">
        <ul class="tabs wc-tabs" role="tablist">
            <?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $tab ) : ?>
                <li class="<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>_tab" id="tab-title-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>">
                    <a href="#tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_' . $key . '_tab_title', esc_html( $tab['title'] ), $key ); ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $tab ) : ?>
            <div class="woocommerce-Tabs-panel woocommerce-Tabs-panel--<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?> panel entry-content wc-tab" id="tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-title-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>">
                <?php call_user_func( $tab['callback'], $key, $tab ); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    </div>  

<?php endif; ?>
```

What could be the possible reason the content is not showing?

Also why `var_dump($tabs);` doesn't show the content but only title and priority?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any text in the text editor (it won't appear in the visual editor) that looks a bit like this:

```html
<div class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper">
<div id="tab-description" class="panel entry-content wc-tab">
```

P.S it didn't appear on here either, but it did after I removed the < and > characters!

Just remove it all, and your text on the webpage will now appear, you don't see this in the visual editor, and could easily be missed unless you view the webpage after your update.

I had a few hundred products with this in, and had to manually remove it :-(

Answer (score -1):

You insert the code your theme in functions.php
Your_theme(Ex:twentysixteen)->functions.php

Comment: sorry, I don't get it..where should I enter my theme name in functions.php?

Comment: You go to see your domain name->wp-content->themes->twentysixteen->functions.php

Comment: I've opened functions.php but not sure what to do there to make the content appear

Comment: I got it solved, but removing unwanted code from functions.php that adds custom code. thanks

Comment: @112233 That's not working, I think you did something more.